# Background/background image not working?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm practicing building a Harley Davidson website and I've encountered a strange issue regarding 'background' and 'background-image'.

A 404 type error keeps appearing in the console:

```
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2
i @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
ready @ jquery.min.js:2
K @ jquery.min.js:2
jquery.min.js:2 GET  file:///Users/benjamingibbs/Desktop/Harley%20Davidson/css/images/austin-neill-174636.jpg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

There is nothing wrong with the file-path. The image loads when I use an 'img' tag inside a div also the logo appears from the same directory.

```
.jumbotron {
  background: url("images/austin-neill-174636.jpg");
}
```

Why is the image not appearing?

- Tried 'body' 'background:' as well but nothing.

Comment: Are you loading the image inside a css file? If yes, is the css file in the same location as the HTML file?

Comment: Please provide the path where the css and html files are located, so we could see where the problem comes from

Comment: Should also mention if you're loading the image from a JavaScript file, and that file isn't in the same directory as the HTML file, then the path would need to be updated.

Comment: Is the `images` folder inside the `css` folder? Because the URL path on the CSS file will be relative to where the .css file is. In this case it's searching the image at `/css/images/`. Maybe you'd want that to be `/images/` instead, which would be accomplished by using `background: url("../images/austin-neill-174636.jpg")` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your images folder in the same folder as your css file? Because if not, your url should look like this:

```
background: url("../images/austin-neill-174636.jpg");
```

Including the `../` escapes the current folder to the images folder in your main project directory.

Answer (score 0):

How your project is structured? If you look at the error your path is:

`.../css/images/austin-neill-174636.jpg`

Does your images folder is at the same level of your CSS folder?

If your project structure is like this:

```
/images
/css
```

You need to go a level higher. Try this instead:

```
.jumbotron {
  background: url("../images/austin-neill-174636.jpg");
}
```