# Background-image property is not working, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: css, background-image

I have struggling to get my background image to work in css. i understand that background-color overrides the background-image property.

```
body {
 background-image: url("images/Body-image.png");
 background-position: center center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: cover;
      }
```

this is my css and i don't know why nothing is happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Background/background image not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43029067/background-background-image-not-working)

Comment: Is your image location correct? Have you checked the console output?

Comment: As the other commenters are saying, probably because your url is looking for your images folder in the wrong location. At least, that's the reason this comes up 90% of the time or more.

Comment: Yeah maybe try `./images/Body-image.png`